# move emails for readable access to another account or backup

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, backup

I have an office 365 email account from my work that I moved on from and I've important emails with technical stuff that I'd like to keep for reference.

The email is still configured in my outlook prompting me nagging messages every now and then while I've my additional emails account configured in outlook as well.

1. How can I get rid of this annoying message prompting me to autodiscover or enter password every-time I start outlook
2. What is the best way to keep these emails with search and readable access. Should I move these emails to another email configured email account or what?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Move them to a PST and disconnect the account ?

Comment: Thanks. I'd need more details, Will the pst be readable and connected to my outlook so I can search and read emails as I need

Comment: You can export your emails to a .olm file, this file is readable. For your reference:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-items-to-an-archive-file-in-outlook-for-mac-281a62bf-cc42-46b1-9ad5-6bda80ca3106